# Issues accessing returned JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to send a JQuery AJAX post to a PHP page, and return a variable back to the Javascript.

Javascript

```
var username = $("#regFormUsername").val();
$.post("ajax/registrationcheck.php",{username:username},function(result){
    console.log(data);
    //I have also tried console.log(data.test);
});
```

PHP

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$data['test'] = $username;
echo json_encode($data);
```

I get "ReferenceError: data is not defined" for both console.log(data.test) and (data).

The response in Firebug is {"test":"asd"}

Also, I know the code is just returning what I am posting to PHP, but it's currently just being tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling it `result`, when you're trying to access `data`:

```
$.post("ajax/registrationcheck.php",{username:username},function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //I have also tried console.log(data.test);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you passing `result` param and expecting `data`. You need to define `data` as argument instead:

```
$.post("ajax/registrationcheck.php",{username:username},function(data){
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just learning JQuery so a simple noob mistake ended up taking me an hour of googling. :) You rock.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `result` you must pass `data`

```
 $.post("ajax/registrationcheck.php",{username:username},function(data){
});
```